# Build Farm Output is Difficult to Read

Tags: ros, buildfarm, build, jenkins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why do I need to look through over 1000 lines of output to figure out what went wrong with the build?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/113156/build-farm-output-is-difficult-to-read/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2013-12-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you don't provide the full output, you may miss important things that happen during the build. If the information is not logged it is gone because you don't have access to the build environment for introspection afterwards.

When viewing a failed build I usually start by searching for "error" caps insensitively and find what the error is and work back from there. Using this technique, especially searching from the bottom it usually takes only a couple of seconds to find the failure in a log.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-12-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-12-26**:
Great tip that I should've asked long ago. I also search `not found`.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2013-12-27**:
That is a good tip, but that doesn't alleviate the essential usability problem. I don't argue having access to the log. It's that it doesn't provide any high level information to give a hint other than reading the log. This answer seems to just be RTFM.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-12-27**:
At the highest level you get pass or fail. If you have any suggestions for libraries or algorithms we can apply to them to give a good summary of failures we'd be happy to add them.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-12-27**:
Sounds more like a good enhancement for jenkins (or there might already exist plugins) ?